# Spring Jwt issue authentication issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

**I'm currently developing the backend for a Learning Management System (LMS) website and I'm encountering an issue with JWT token authentication**

[image: when try to log in to]

> After successfully logging into the system using a username and
> password, I obtain a JWT token without any issues

[image: i get a forbidden here]

> However, when I attempt to authenticate using this JWT token, I consistently receive a "Forbidden" error.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final AccUserDetailsService userService;
    private final JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filterService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("api/staff/**").hasAnyRole("STAFF","ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("api/student/**").hasRole("STUDENT")
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.addFilterBefore(filterService, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/logging", "/welcome","api/signup","/api/authenticate");
    }

}
```

> this is my security configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class JwtAuthenticationProvider {
    @Value("${api.jwtSecret}")
    private String secret;

    private final int TOKEN_VALIDITY = 5 * 60 * 60;

    public String generateToken(String userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails);
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TOKEN_VALIDITY * 1000))
                .signWith(getSigningKey(),SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();

    }

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    private Key getSigningKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secret);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    private Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);

    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSigningKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));

    }

}
```

> and this is my jwtconfiguration class

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtAuthenticationProvider tokenService;
    private final AccUserDetailsService accUserDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = tokenService.getUsernameFromToken(jwt);
        }
        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.accUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(tokenService.validateToken(jwt,userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

> filter service provided here

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

    private final AccountService accountService;
    private final AuthService authService;
    
    @GetMapping("/api/admin/")
    public String admin(){
        return ("<h1>Welcome admin<h1>");
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/signup")
    public String createAccount(@RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest){
        accountService.signup(signUpRequest);
        return "test";
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<APIResponse<?>> createAccount(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) throws AuthenticationException {
        LoginResponse loginResponse = authService.userAuthenticate(loginRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new APIResponse<>(ResponseCode.SUCCESS_LOGIN,loginResponse));
    }
    
}
```

> Controller class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dsm</groupId>
    <artifactId>dsm</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dsm</name>
    <description>Driving </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>0.11.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've gone through my codebase and configurations, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. If anyone has experience with this specific combination of Java and Spring versions, I'd really appreciate your assistance in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: i hope you are aware that handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous, and there is an active choice to not have this type of authentication built into spring security. Thats why you had to build all this custom code. Whatever tutorial you followed has no idea how security works and no one should build this type of authentication. Please reada the officcial doccs on how to build proper security.

Comment: what should i use instead of jwt?

Comment: cookies are handed out to browsers, and jwt are used internally between microserives. I cant teach you security in a comment, but i suggest you read the oauth2 spec and the open ID connect spec, thets were JWTs are used. Nothing else. Also i suggest that you actually take the time and read the spring docs before asking

Comment: no, I didn't ask you to teach spring security in a comment, I wanted to know alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UserDetails` class contains authorities.

You are using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` with your `UserDetails` authorities.

If you are setting it in your `SecurityContextHolder`.

try using `hasAuthority` or `hasAnyAuthority` instead of `hasRole` or `hasAnyRole`.

```
.requestMatchers("api/student/**").hasAuthority("STUDENT") 
                .requestMatchers("api/staff/**").hasAnyAuthority("STAFF","ADMIN")
```

Make sure your role like `STUDENT` ,`STAFF` are included in your `UserDetails's` authorities.

Hope it helps.